# Returning html string from Rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to build a formatted html string using a rails helper method, which lives in **application_helper.rb**.

```
def comment_posted_tag(actor_id,date)
  ... irrelevant code removed
  str =  "<b>" + actor_name + "</b>" + " on " + date.strftime("%d %b %Y at %H:%M")
  return str.html_safe
end
```

I'm calling it like this in the view:

```
<%= comment_posted_tag(dialog_comment.actor_id,dialog_comment.updated_at) %>
```

For some reason the  tags are not coming through. Ideally I'd like to attached a css class to the **actor_name** string. I've tried it with and without the html_safe but neither work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always use `content_tag` for this kind of job:

```
def comment_posted_tag(actor_name, date)
  content_tag(:span, :class => 'yours') do
    content_tag(:b, actor_name) + ' on ' + date.strftime("%d %b %Y at %H:%M")
  end
end
```